# Where does the configuration block of an execution actually go in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

It seems a very simple question, but something is not working right.

So given a `pom.xml` file I wanted to use the `properties-maven-plugin`. If I copy what is [in the docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html), meaning this code:

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputFile>
                   ${project.baseDir}/app.properties
              </outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And then I run using `mvn properties:write-project-properties`, I get an error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:write-project-properties (default-cli) on project backend: The parameters 'outputFile' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:write-project-properties are missing or invalid
```

BUT

when I edit the code above and move the `configuration` right next to `executions` and then run the command, everything works (even though IntelliJ underlines the `configuration` expression with red saying `properties 'child' tag should be defined`.

```xml
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFile>
                        ${project.baseDir}/app.properties
                    </outputFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I just randomly stumbled upon [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931384/4420543) that solved this issue.

Why is this happening and where are the documentations for maven that would prevent me from spending couple hours wasting on a configuration file next time I need something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is as follows:

- The first POM defines an execution *for the Maven lifecycle* together with its configuration. So it is meant to run when you call something like `mvn clean install`. With the configuration inside the execution, you just configured that execution (not any other execution, like the one you started from command line).
- The second POM has a global configuration for the plugin goal. The execution in the POM does not matter (you can just delete it), but your command line execution will pick up this global configuration.

Does this make the behaviour more understandable?